# Young slit experiment intensity integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, double-slit-experiment, calculus

I have a little problem with this integral which shows up in a demonstration about the intensity at a point M on a screen. Primitive of $\cos (ax+b)$ is $\frac{1}{a}$($\sin (ax +b))$. I do not understand how we get to the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Use double angle formulae.

## Long Answer

Ok so let us work through this systematically. We start with the intergral:

$$I_M=\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}Kdx \left[1+\cos \left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \left(\frac{x'}{D}+\frac{x}{D}\right)\right)\right]$$
(I have added an extra bracket to make things clearer).

Intergratio of the first term is trivial:
$$\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}Kdx (1)=\left[Kx\right]^{1/2}_{-1/2}$$
$$=K\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=K$$
The second term (as you indicate in the question) gives:

$$I_2=\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}Kdx \cos \left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \left(\frac{x'}{D}+\frac{x}{D}\right)\right)=\left[k\frac{\lambda D}{2\pi S_1 S_2}\sin\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \left(\frac{x'}{D}+\frac{x}{D}\right)\right)\right]^{1/2}_{-1/2}$$
$$=k\frac{\lambda D}{2\pi S_1 S_2}\left(\sin\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \left(\frac{x'}{D}+\frac{1}{2D}\right)\right)-\sin\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \left(\frac{x'}{D}-\frac{1}{2D}\right)\right)\right)$$
We now use double angle formulae:
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$ on both $\sin$ terms:
and
$$\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$$I_2=K\frac{\lambda D}{2\pi S_1 S_2}\left(\sin\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \frac{x'}{D}\right)\cos\left( 2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda}\frac{1}{2D}\right)+\cos\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \frac{x'}{D}\right)\sin\left( 2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda}\frac{1}{2D}\right)\right.$$
$$\left.-\sin\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \frac{x'}{D}\right)\cos\left( 2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda}\frac{1}{2D}\right)+\cos\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \frac{x'}{D}\right)\sin\left( 2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda}\frac{1}{2D}\right)\right)$$
$$I_2=K\frac{\lambda D}{\pi S_1S_2}\cos\left(2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda} \frac{x'}{D}\right)\sin\left( 2\pi \frac{S_1S_2}{\lambda}\frac{1}{2D}\right)$$
which is the second term on the second line.